# Errors in setting up an mlvpn environment - facing issues in tunnels getting up

Tags: vpn, bandwidth

[mlvpn](http://mlvpn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_mlvpn.html) tunnels are not getting up on both sides. Giving device or resource busy error every time.

The configurations are:

- This is the file in client side of `mlvpn.conf`:

  ```
  [general]
  statuscommand = "/etc/mlvpn/mlvpn0_updown.sh"
  tuntap = "tun"
  mode = "client"
  interface_name = "mlvpn0"
  timeout = 30
  password = "you have not changed me yet?"
  reorder_buffer_size = 64
  loss_tolerence = 50

  [filters]

  [adsl1]
  bindhost = "172.20.10.22"
  remotehost = "server ip"
  remoteport = 5080

  [adsl2]
  bindhost = "192.168.42.130"
  remotehost = "server_ip"
  remoteport = 5081
  ```
- This is the updown script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  error=0; trap "error=$((error|1))" ERR

  tuntap_intf="$1"
  newstatus="$2"
  rtun="$3"

  [ -z "$newstatus" ] && exit 1

  (
  if [ "$newstatus" = "tuntap_up" ]; then
      echo "$tuntap_intf setup"
      /sbin/ip link set dev $tuntap_intf mtu 1400 up
      /sbin/route add proof.ovh.net dev $tuntap_intf
  elif [ "$newstatus" = "tuntap_down" ]; then
      echo "$tuntap_intf shutdown"
      /sbin/route del proof.ovh.net dev $tuntap_intf
  elif [ "$newstatus" = "rtun_up" ]; then
      echo "rtun [${rtun}] is up"
  elif [ "$newstatus" = "rtun_down" ]; then
      echo "rtun [${rtun}] is down"
  fi
  ) >> /var/log/mlvpn_commands.log 2>&1

  exit $errors
  ```

These are my errors:

```
    mlvpn0:tun or device or resource busy.
```